# HTML/CSS Border Around Multiple Elements

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to get a border around my image and paragraphs items but I can't figure out how to do it. I encased them in divs and added a class to them but the background color and border effects do nothing. This is what i'm shooting for: [image]

this is what my HTML code looks like for this section:

```
<div class="pair">
                <a href="GPA_Calc_Screen.png">
                    <img src="GPA_Calc_Screen.png" alt""> <!--Relative img path -->
                </a>

                <p>
                        This is a custom GPA Calculator, and what I like to think is the first real app that I made. Going to Georgia Tech, and college in general, this is a vital asset. Although at GT we don't operate on the plus/minus system, I added a setting in which you can edit that if you want.
                </p>
        </div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.pair div {
    display: block;
    /*padding: 5px;
    clear: right;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: red;*/
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to add div in front of .pair when you are doing class without id based
you just keep

```
.pair  {
      border: 3px rgb(86, 10, 10) solid;
      padding: 9px;
      display: block;        
 }   

 <div class="pair">
   <a href="GPA_Calc_Screen.png">
     <img src="sourceofimage.png" alt""> <!--Relative img path -->
   </a>
   <p>
     your text
   </p>
 </div>
```

for bottom div also you need to add this "pair" class.

Comment: @Josephhooper what is the output?

Comment: adding the overflow:auto fixed it, what does that do exactly?

Comment: I have added floating to left

Answer (score 0):

You have to add border in .pair class

```
.pair div
{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: right;
    width: 100%;  
}
.pair
{
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as in this I have made for you [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74869pL5/)

If you want use '`.pair div {}`' you need to place that div inside of div with `.pair` class

```
.pair{
display: block;
padding: 5px;
clear: right;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 5px solid #ff0000;
background: orange;
}
```

Comment: this worked, but the border/background isnt surround the pictures and paragraph it's below it

Comment: read comments placed in fiddle css box, there is with example

Comment: I have it just like it's set up it fiddle but no lick. Maybe because of the way I have my floats set up for my image and paragraph?

Comment: As well you can go back to your code you posted first. Remove 'div' from .pair div {} and, uncomment your style part and add :
`
  border-style: solid;
`
I updated fiddle for this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem ,just go to the jsfiddle here[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfjgLzn3/)

```css
div {
    border: 3px solid #8AC007;
}

.img1 {
    float: left;
}

.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="clearfix">
 <img class="img2" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUHgZRyJPa3nt3V4hgxAN0K2iFn1MaoYluUIwswewquau2nkdRaA" width="100" height="300">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo culpa, maiores veritatis minima sequi earum. Ad perspiciatis molestias, illum saepe nihil quo nam dignissimos ducimus similique consequatur veniam facilis iure! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit ullam perferendis esse deserunt vel ea alias, officia earum, natus, aspernatur porro. Maiores assumenda distinctio accusantium laudantium voluptate explicabo, aliquid sint.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```